# How can I configure myhostname to work with Postfix?

Tags: postfix, hostname

I'm going through the process of setting up a Discourse forum on my server (Ubuntu 12.04 x64) and am getting stuck at the point where I have to configure mailers.

I'm following Discourse's instructions and am stuck trying to [configure postfix for Mandrill](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23060367-Can-I-configure-Postfix-to-send-through-Mandrill-). It is says to check my fully-qualified domain name by typing `hostname -f`

When I enter in `hostname -f`, I get `localhost`. As far as I know, entering in `hostname -f` should return `mydomainname.com`.

When I just enter in `hostname`, I get `mydomainname` which is correct because that is what I set my hostname to in `/etc/hostname`.

Looking at some of my other settings, my `/etc/hosts` file reads:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost mydomainname
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

And in my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file, I have `myhostname` set like this:

`myhostname = mydomainname.mydomainname.com`

(Should this be `myhostname = mail.mydomainname.com` instead?)

And `mydestination` is the following:

`mydestination = mydomainname.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost`

I'm not that familiar with configuring hostnames. I've been reading [Postfix's instructions](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#myhostname), but haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Any help on how to get this to work would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple files involved in setting up a proper Ubuntu server (12.04.x) for email. Here's the list of those as available at the moment in my server.

- **`/etc/hosts`** - This file in my Ubuntu server has the following line, among other lines

  ```
  127.0.1.1 myhostname.mydomainname.tld myhostname
  ```

  Note: Please *never* touch the line that contains `127.0.0.1`. It may be generated and / or updated by the web host upon each reboot.
- **`/etc/hostname`** - This file in my Ubuntu server has the following content.

  ```
  myhostname
  ```
- **`/etc/mailname`** - This file in my Ubuntu server has the following content.

  ```
  mydomainname.tld
  ```
- **`/etc/postfix/main.cf`** - This file in my Ubuntu server has the following lines, among others...

  ```
  myorigin      = /etc/mailname
  myhostname    = myhostname.mydomainname.tld
  mydestination = localhost, myhostname.mydomainname.tld
  ```

Once all the above files have the expected content, you may run the following commands to let them all work together while sending emails...

```
$ sudo hostname -F /etc/hostname
$ sudo service postfix restart
```

If you have a server, exclusively for email, I'd recommend keeping the `hostname` as `mail`. Otherwise, use any `hostname` and keeping sending the emails as `mydomainname.tld` using Mandrill.

Make sure, everything works as expected even upon a reboot. You wouldn't want your web host to override any files upon reboot, that may affect the email sending / receiving.

I hope that helps.

Comment: My answer is not about how to receive emails from outside!

Comment: I'm [trying to understand the siginificance of `/etc/mailname`](https://serverfault.com/questions/1063236/what-role-does-etc-mailname-play-in-postfix). I can't find anything in postfix's documentation on it.

Comment: The `hostname -F /etc/hostname` seems to be a mandatory step (or rebooting I presume), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make changes in your `/etc/hosts` file as below :

```
<IP>   <FQDN>  <ALIAS>
```

So in your case it would be :

```
127.0.0.1  mail.mydomainname.com  mail
```

then do following changes :

if you are using Ubuntu:

Edit /etc/hostname and change to the new value,

```
nano /etc/hostname
```

if you are using RHEL/CentOS:

Edit: `/etc/sysconfig/network`

```
HOSTNAME=mail.mydomainname.com
```

then you can run following command to apply changes .

```
hostname mail
```

then check.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the `/etc/hosts` file. Then I tried `echo "mail" > /etc/hostname` and got `-bash: /etc/hostname: Permission denied` (even when using sudo). Can I just open up the `/etc/hostname` and change the hostname to mail? Is it safe to change the name?

Comment: @JohnKellyFerguson try with `sudo` or edit file manually

Comment: I tried `sudo echo "mail" > /etc/hostname` and got `-bash: /etc/hostname: Permission denied`.

Comment: have you tried with manualy edit that file ?

Comment: I am logged into my server as `deploy@myname`. When I go to edit the file using sudo, I change `myname` to `mail` and then save and exit. I then get a message saying: `sudo: unable to resolve host myname`.

Comment: sorry, my mistack, in steps sequence.. first we need to run `sudo hostname mail` set hostname, then to permanent save, need to add in `/etc/hostname`

Comment: @JohnKellyFerguson I have tested above steps in my ubuntu, so please once do check and let me know if you are facing any issue..