# What role does /etc/mailname play in postfix?

Tags: postfix

I'm troubleshooting a postfix configuration, and `/etc/mailname` is often mentioned in this context. What exactly is its role? Does it in some way relate to postfix's `myorigin`/`myhostname`/`mydomain` config variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can (but you are in no way forced to) configure postfix to read that file. [Debian-based systems ship configuration](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#s-mail-transport-agents) that does that. Search your configuration to see if yours is referencing the file:

```
# postconf | grep mailname
myorigin = /etc/mailname
```

**You could just as well have put your verbatim domain name directly into `main.cf` instead of using the path to instruct postfix to read from there.**

You can get the full and read about the individual effects list by searching for `myorigin` in [`man 5 postconf`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html).

The most obvious place this is used in common setups is then the `append_at_myorigin` feature, where submitting mail not specifying a domain will have the domain - potentially read from that file - appended. Many other Postfix directly use or reference $myorigin.